# Custom Marker icon Google Maps iOS with image in image?

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I try to create many markers in map with icon is a png image like placeholder.
After that i want to set an other image inside of each placeholder.

It [looks like this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/84811083.png).
My problem is how to set image inside image of marker.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write code which takes the background image (eg the frame) and adds on the sub-image (eg the food picture), to create a combined `UIImage`. Then you could use the combined `UIImage` as the marker's icon.

Check out these questions for some examples of how to draw 2 `UIImage` objects into a single `UIImage`:

[Draw another image on a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656745/draw-another-image-on-a-uiimage)

[Attempting to draw image on top of another image using a touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054587/attempting-to-draw-image-on-top-of-another-image-using-a-touch-event)